# OS161 : TLB miss on Load

Tags: c, memory-management, mips, tlb, os161

I have a TLB miss on load error when I run the fork test , I understand this is due to passing wrong stackptr to mips_usermode , my implementation seems to revolve around few suggestions over here, would be grateful if I get corrected her. My code below is provided as entry point function in thread_fork. Am i missin any thing ?

```
void
enter_forked_process(void *junk,unsigned long num)
{

        kprintf("\n entered enter_fork_process");
        struct trapframe tf = (*((struct trapframe *) junk));


        (void) num;


        kprintf("\n copied tf from from parent to child");
        tf.tf_v0 = 0;
        tf.tf_a3 = 0;
        tf.tf_epc += 4;
        kprintf("abt to enter mips_ usermode");
        mips_usermode(&tf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy parent thread's address space before you call `thread_fork`, and pass the address space pointer as the second parameter of `enter_forked_process`. And in `enter_forked_process`, you have to fill the address space into `curthread->t_addrspace`. Otherwise, you'll get the `TLB miss on load` error, since current thread (the child)'s address space is not initialized.

For more details about OS161 fork system call, please refer to this blog. And `child_forkentry` there is more or less the same as your `enter_forked_process`.
http://jhshi.me/2012/03/11/os161-fork-system-call/index.html

Comment: also synchronization has to be taken care of...here

Comment: The link is broken. Here is a [new one](http://jhshi.me/2012/03/11/os161-fork-system-call/index.html#.XeOtF9VOlhE).